# Locking in a naive concurrent hash map

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I was going through the ConcurrentHashMap implementation in Java and looks like by default there are 16 locks used and this number changes dynamically.

Assume a naive implementation of a concurrent hashmap where data is stored in a list:  `List<Bin<X, Y>>` . List starts with a size 32 and then the index is calculated using `getHashCode()` function modulo current capacity of the list

```
class Bin<X, Y> {
    List<Pair<X, Y>> myList;
    ReentrantReadWriteLock lock;

    void put(X key, Y value){
    //acquire write lock
    }

    void  Pair<X, Y> get(X key) {
    //acquire read lock
    }
}
```

I was wondering what are the downsides of having a lock per bin in the naive implementation mentioned above. One major downside I could think of is:

- Additional memory overhead of `Pair`, `ReentrantReadWriteLock` and `Bin` object for every key/value in the map

What is the impact on CPU when there are too many locks? More downsides of this approach?

Comment: It's like the capacity/fillfactor trade-off with a regular `HashMap`. Depends on what you need. That's why they're configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Of course when you call `readLock()/writeLock()` on `Lock` object there would be some overhead on this locking, at least some `cas` operations, in worst case thread blocking.

There is no much CPU impact because in case of `Lock`(`ReentrantReadWriteLock` in your case) it's implemented based on `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` and uses `cas` operations inside.

To eliminate overhead on storing multiple `ReentrantReadWriteLock` you can either just use `synchronized` on particular `pair`(of course then you would be unavailable to use read/write lock optimization, but since each bucket is just a `Pair`, not a collection, I think there shouldn't be much to lose here, also jvm can optimize `synchronized` sections in various ways).